# SQL: PIVOT with join

Tags: sql, pivot, crosstab

Newbie question:

I have table below

```
Period Customer Balance
40     1        10
40     2        15
39     1        9
38     1        10
38     2        20
```

I would like to order it so that I have one column for each period,

```
Customer BalancePeriod38 BalancePeriod39 BalancePeriod40
1              10              9               10
2              15              .               20
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Its called PIVOT. Millions of posts on SO about it across every RDBMS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can *pivot* the data using aggregation with case:

```
select customer,
    sum(case when period = 38 then balance else 0 end) as balance_period_38,
    sum(case when period = 39 then balance else 0 end) as balance_period_39,
    sum(case when period = 40 then balance else 0 end) as balance_period_40
from your_table
group by customer;
```